# How could webView display ppt in NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, powerpoint, cache-control

This is my code:

```
//1.Create caches

NSString *caches = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
self.filePath = [caches stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xsb.ppt"];

DLog(@"%@",self.filePath);

//2.Create file manager

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//create file
[fileManager createFileAtPath:self.filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];


//Use webView open ppt

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:self.filePath];
self.request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.PPTWebView loadRequest:self.request];
```

webView error:

> cuoweuError Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102

Who can tell me why?

Comment: How did you declare the `PPTWebView` ? What does `DLog(@"%@",self.filePath);` print ? And are you sure the fileManager did his job (check with `BOOL isItThere = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:self.filePath];`) ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete

```
[fileManager createFileAtPath:self.filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
```

Otherwise the file will be overwritten.

If you want to be sure that the powerpoint file is handled correctly by the webview you can try to add the .ppt file to your project and then open it like this:

```
NSString * pathToPowerPointFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                        pathForResource:@"xsb"
                        ofType:@"ppt"];

[self.PPTWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToPowerPointFile]]];
```